# Rails. how to display the data by column name

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use Rails 4. 
I use structure

```
@users  =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

@users.each do |row| %> 

  puts user[0] # id--> 1,2,3,4,5,6 

end

@users.fields do |field| %> 

  puts field.name # --> id, login, password.....

end
```

how to display the data by column name?
for example

```
@users.first.field['id']
```

Comment: Then spend some time to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(` will run the sql but not return anything (or return `nil`, more accurately).  To load the records into memory do

```
@users = User.all
```

You don't describe what you want very well.  If you literally want "1,2,3,4,5,6" you could do

```
@users.map(&:id).join(",")
```

if you wanted, for example, to do a table showing all the user data you could do (in your view)

```
<% cols = User.column_names %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <% cols.each do |col| %>
        <th><%= col %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <% cols.each do |col| %>
          <td><%= user.send(col) %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Like i say i don't know if this is what you actually want to do.  Your requirements are a very messy and very vague.

**EDIT**

If you want to load data out of the database without using an AR model then you can do

```
@users = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select * from users")
```

this will give you an array of hashes like this

```
[{"id" => "1", "name" => "foo", "bar" => "baz"}, {"id" => "2", "name" => "chunky", "bar" => "bacon"}, .... ]
```

which you could then access like

```
user = @users.first #you've got a hash now
aname = user["name"]
```